# Adding python functionality to Tkinter front end

Tags: python, tkinter

This is the front end I developed for my application using Tkinter:

```
from Tkinter import *
class Example(Frame):
def __init__(self, parent):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)   
    self.parent = parent
    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):

    self.parent.title("Simple")
    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    frame = Frame(self, relief="flat", borderwidth=1)

    label=Label(frame,text="Scope:")
    label.pack(side="left", fill=None, expand=False)

    var = StringVar()
    var.set("today")
    list = OptionMenu(frame, var, "today","yesterday","this week","last week","this month","last month")
    list.pack(side="left", fill=None, expand=False)

    fetchButton = Button(frame, text="Fetch",command=self.handle(var))
    fetchButton.pack(side="left", fill=None, expand=False)

    frame.grid(row=1,column=1,pady=4,padx=5,sticky=W)

    area = Text(self,height=15,width=60)
    area.grid(row=2,column=1,rowspan=1,pady=4,padx=5)

    scroll = Scrollbar(self)
    scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

    area.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
    scroll.config(command=area.yview)
    scroll.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='nsew')

    quitButton = Button(self, text="Cancel",command=self.quit)
    quitButton.grid(pady=4,padx=5,sticky=W,row=3, column=1)

root = Tk()
app = Example(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Where exactly do I have to put the `handle()` method so it can write repeatedly to the text widget? When I put `handle()` within the `Example` class and use `self.area.insert()`, it shows an error saying

```
Example instance has no attribute 'area'
```

Please help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the function object to the Button instance, not a function call. i.e.

```
fetchButton = Button(frame, text="Fetch",command=self.handle)
```

To make the handle work in the context of the rest of the code:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title("Simple")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.frame = Frame(self, relief="flat", borderwidth=1)
        self.frame.grid(row=1,column=1,pady=4,padx=5,sticky=W)
        self.label=Label(self.frame,text="Scope:")
        self.label.pack(side="left", fill=None, expand=False)

        self.var = StringVar()
        self.var.set("today")

        self.list = OptionMenu(self.frame, self.var, "today","yesterday",
                               "this week","last week","this month",
                               "last month")
        self.list.pack(side="left", fill=None, expand=False)

        self.fetchButton = Button(self.frame, text="Fetch",command=self.handle)
        self.fetchButton.pack(side="left", fill=None, expand=False)

        self.area = Text(self,height=15,width=60)
        self.area.grid(row=2,column=1,rowspan=1,pady=4,padx=5)

        self.scroll = Scrollbar(self)
        self.scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        self.area.config(yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)
        self.scroll.config(command=self.area.yview)
        self.scroll.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='nsew')

        self.quitButton = Button(self, text="Cancel",command=self.quit)
        self.quitButton.grid(pady=4,padx=5,sticky=W,row=3, column=1)

    def handle(self):
        self.area.delete(1.0, END)
        self.area.insert(CURRENT,self.var.get())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Declaring your widgets as attributes will save you a lot of pain an suffering as your application expands. Also keeping references to everything in Tk can stop some unwanted garbage collection, particularly with images in `Label` instances.

It is also worth noting that using `grid` and `pack` interchangeably is likely to lead to bugs later on.

Comment: The reason you were getting that error is because you did not declare `area` as an attribute. If you change all your `area` instances to `self.area`, this will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, works cool. But my `handle()` method contains some heavy functionality and it takes at least 5 mins for the first `self.area.insert()` to be called. When I click on the window in the meantime, the title bar shows `Not Responding` and the whole window goes gray. Some way to handle that?

Comment: looks like I have to use multithreading to tackle `Not Responding`. thanks anyway.

Comment: Yep, sounds like you need to spawn the handle method in a new thread.